# Translation of the Aruch haShulchan

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, aruch-hashulchan

Is there a translation of the Aruch haShulchan available anywhere? If so, does it include the Hebrew? Is it in print or online? Does it follow tzurat hadaf?

Comment: A complete translation does not exist wish it did,it really is an essential part of halacha

Comment: http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Arukh_ha-Shulchan

Comment: Anything on Shulchan Aruch other than M"B (O"Ch) translated?

Comment: Is there a translation of the entire Shulchan Aruch online?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah, wondering the same thing myself, although in print.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's probably empty because people are confused by the presence of "Author's Introduction" before _Orach Chayim_ instead of _Choshen Mishpat_.

Answer (score 4):

The [first volume](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1602804591) of a translation of the Aruch HaShulchan into English by R Ilan Segal has now been published, it covers chapters 242-292 of Orach Chaim (on the laws of Shabbat).

It has been favorably reviewed [here](http://torahbookreviews.blogspot.com/2021/10/aruch-hashulchan-in-english.html) by R Ari Enkin, [here](https://joshyuter.com/2021/07/30/reviews/book-review-aruch-hashulchan-in-english/) by R Josh Yuter and [here](https://jewishbookreview.wordpress.com/2021/12/31/aruch-hashulchan-in-english-new-review/) by R Micha Berger. It does include the Hebrew as you can see on a screenshot in R Yuter's review.